# Python - Selenium Next Page with condition

Tags: python, selenium

I'm pretty new to python, I have a webpage that has 50 pages. each page has 50 users. I need to multi-select users on one page after another then click on download data. There's one limitation that I can only download data for 500 users at once. So I need to multi-select the users in the first 10 pages then download their data and then multi-select the users in the next 10 pages then download and etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class Runtest():
    def test(self):
        driver_location = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driver_location
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_location)
        driver.get("http://example.com/")

        Next_Page = "XPATH"
        Multi_Select = "XPATH2"
        Download_Data = "XPATH3"
       driver.find_element_by_xpath(Multi_Select).click()
       driver.find_element_by_xpath(Next_Page).click()
       driver.find_element_by_xpath(Download_Data).click()
```

Would appreciate some guidance on how to get that condition done.

Answer (score 0):

I have one method that might be useful for you,
you can always create for loop or while loop according to your need. As you want to get 500 users as once so, you can check difference between two pages link and put values according to it. in most of cases difference in url is always according to page number so, please refer the code and put full link of real website or change the name if it's confidential.

```
values = list(range(1,10))
list = ['https://www.example.com?page=' + str(i) for i in values ]

for i in list:
    driver.get(i)
    select_all =  driver.find_element_by_xpath(Multi_Select).click()
    download_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath(Download_Data).click()
```

Over here, it will download user data and when it exceed it gives error.